# Installing Openshift CodeReady Containers on Manjaro

Tags: openshift, yum, manjaro

I want to install Openshift CodeReady Containers (local dev version) on Manjaro. It is not officially supported, but I've found a few sources saying there are no major issues so I wanted to try it out.

I downloaded the tool from redhat website: https://console.redhat.com/openshift/downloads#tool-crc

After running `cdc setup`, and installing a few dependencies, I'm stuck on the following problem:

> WARN unsupported distribution &{32;1;24;144;200 Manjaro Linux
> manjaro arch Manjaro Linux  https://manjaro.org/ https://manjaro.org/
> [https://bugs.manjaro.org/}](https://bugs.manjaro.org/%7D), trying to install libvirt with yum
>
> Could not install required packages:  exit status 127: /bin/sh: line
> 1: yum: command not found

I installed libvirt with yay, but it had no effect. So I wanted to install yum:
`yay yum`
But got the following issue:

> -> Could not find all required packages:
> urlgrabber (Wanted by: yum)

I managed to install urlgrabber with pip, but it didn't change anything.

Any ideas for where do I go from here? Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have installed libvirt, but haven't configured it. After following this tutorial on setting up the kvm driver:
https://docs.okd.io/3.11/minishift/getting-started/setting-up-virtualization-environment.html#setting-up-kvm-driver

I managed to run Openshift CodeReady Containers